# An operation on a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested list, and I want each sublist to be connected by a <-> symbol between the first and third elements and between the second and fourth elements.
For example,

```
a = {{1, 2, 7, 8}, {3, 4, 6, 7}}
```

I'd like to get the following output:

```
{1 <-> 7, 2 <-> 8, 3 <-> 6, 4 <-> 7}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `{#[[1]] <-> #[[3]], #[[2]] <-> #[[4]]} & /@ a // Flatten`

Comment: Thanks!  Bob.  Looks like I need to lay the groundwork.

Comment: `Map[Sequence@@BlockMap[TwoWayRule @@ #[[{1, -1}]] &, #, 3, 1] &]@a`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to @BobHanlon's suggestion in the comments:

```
a = {{1, 2, 7, 8}, {3, 4, 6, 7}};

Splice@{# <-> #3, #2 <-> #4} & @@@ a
(* {1 <-> 7, 2 <-> 8, 3 <-> 6, 4 <-> 7} *)
```

The difference is the use of [`Splice`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Splice.html) instead of `Flatten`, and the use of [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) at level 1 (`@@@`) to be able to write `#2` instead of `#[[2]]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
twRule=Thread[TwoWayRule @@ Partition[#, 2]]&;

Splice @* twRule /@ a
```

> ```
> {1 <-> 7, 2 <-> 8, 3 <-> 6, 4 <-> 7}
> ```